# Creating a vector of specific size in a map C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

Hi suppose I want to create a map of the form `map<int, vector<node> >` where node is defined
as

```
struct node{
    string key;
    double pnum;
    node():key(""),pnum(0) {}
};
```

Now If someone gives me a map key, say "Element_1" and a vector size 2 is it alright/safe to create 
the vector under the key "Element_1" as it has been done below?

```
int main(void)
{
    map<string,vector<node> > samplemap;    
    samplemap["Element_1"] = vector<node>(2);
}
```

The above code compiles and I am able to print out the vector stored under the key "Element_1". (Default values printed).

Comment: if it compiles and looks to work, why are you asking this question?

Comment: @Erik: on the other hand, often stuff that compiles and looks to work is actually relying on undefined behavior, and will stop working at the worst possible moment.

Comment: @Erik - I think the question the OP is asking is "is this well formed", i.e. looking beyond "it works for me syndrome". Could be a lot clearer though.

Comment: If you stop to ask a stackoverflow question for all of your code that compiles and works properly, you'll never get anything done ;)

Comment: yes i wanted to ask if the expression is well formed /good practice to write it . I mean usually we declare vectors like vector<node> example(20). In my code the name of the vector is not given. Hence I was doubtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If someone gives me a map key, say "Element_1" and a vector size 2 is it alright/safe to  create the vector under the key "Element_1" as it has been done below?

Yes, my friend. If the key already exists, then it updates the associated value, otherwise it creates a new entry with the  *key* with default value [i.e `vector<node>()`] which then gets updated the specified value [i.e `vector<node>(2)`].

By the way, `vector<node>(2)` creates a vector of size `2`. That means, it will have two elements of type `node` created by calling the default constructor of `node`.

Comment: thank you. I was in doubt because usually we declare vectors like vector<node> example(20). In my code the name of the vector is not given. it is just created as vector<node>(20)

Comment: @Gaurish: `vector<node> example(20)` creates a *named* object, while `vector<node>(20)` creates an anonymous object.